# How to get current EC2 instance state in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instancestate

I'm looking for some code that will return the current instance state regardless of whether the instance is currently running or not.  I found some code that will return the desired result on a running instance, but when trying to find one that will work on stopped instances, I was overwhelmed by a number of similar looking classes that appeared to perform a similar operation, but in the end, did not work or were poorly documented.

Anyway, the running instance version of the code is below:

```
public Integer getInstanceStatus(String instanceId) {
    DescribeInstanceStatusRequest describeInstanceRequest = new DescribeInstanceStatusRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);
    DescribeInstanceStatusResult describeInstanceResult = ec2.describeInstanceStatus(describeInstanceRequest);
    List<InstanceStatus> state = describeInstanceResult.getInstanceStatuses();
    return state.get(0).getInstanceState().getCode();
}
```

So I'm basically looking for the equivalent that does not have the `DescribeInstanceStatus`'s restriction that requires the instance to be running.  I'd assume this is possible since the `getCode()` documentation shows it as being able to return the value 80 which denotes a **stopped** instance.

Answer (score 2):

And once again, I answer my own question... Though I am open to other suggestions.

```
public Integer getInstanceStatus(String instanceId) {
    DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstanceRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);
    DescribeInstancesResult describeInstanceResult = ec2.describeInstances(describeInstanceRequest);
    InstanceState state = describeInstanceResult.getReservations().get(0).getInstances().get(0).getState();
    return state.getCode();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set `withIncludeAllInstances(true)` on your request then you can get states for the not running instances.

```
DescribeInstanceStatusResult result = ec2.describeInstanceStatus(new DescribeInstanceStatusRequest()
                .withInstanceIds(instanceIds).withIncludeAllInstances(true));
```